# Running Count of Unique Identifier Occurrences in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to get a running count of uses over time by a unique identifier,

E.G.

```
Date     UniqueID Running Count
1/1/2019 234567   1
1/1/2019 123456   1
1/2/2019 234567   2
1/3/2019 234567   3
1/3/2019 123456   2
```

Basically I want to be able to see that on 1/3/2019 that was the 3rd time that UniqueID 234567 showed up in the data.

I tried:

```
SELECT Date, UniqueID,
       count(UniqueID) OVER (ORDER BY Date, UniqueID rows unbounded preceding) AS RunningTotal
```

but this just does a overall running total, so it doesn't reset with a new UniqueID

```
SELECT Date, UniqueID, count(UniqueID) OVER (ORDER BY Date, UniqueID rows unbounded preceding) AS RunningTotal
```

Is there anything I could do to make it reset for each UniqueID

Comment: Add a `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: @SamuelHarris . . . How is the "2" calculated in the last row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I forgot to add a row! I fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `2` in the last row is a typo, you want either `ROW_NUMBER()` or `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT Date, UniqueID,
       ROW_NUMBER(UniqueID) OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY Date) AS RunningTotal
```

You would use `DENSE_RANK()` if you could have duplicates on one day that you wanted to count only once.

By the way, you *could* also express this using `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT Date, UniqueID,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY Date) AS RunningTotal
```

There are some subtle differences in the handling of duplicate values.  Normally, `COUNT()` is not used for this purpose because the ranking functions are so pervasive (and useful).